# wrap a macro expansion method

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-macros

I am trying to wrap the play json writes macro expansion

`def encoder[T] = Json.writes[T]`

But the `T` is unknown , so that won't compile, it complains

`no unapply method found`

I know I can replace `Json.writes[T]` with `JsMacroImpl.reads` expansion.
Is there a better way doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar problem some time back. you can do something like this.

create an object and inside write encoder method as a macro method.

```
object SomeObj {
  def encoder[T] = macro encoderRedirect_impl[T]

  def encoderRedirect_impl[T : c.WeekTypeTag](c:Context) = {
    q"Json.writes[${c.weakTypeOf[T]}]"
  }
}
```

This is a macro redirect for my understanding. but you have to write this code in seperate project and use it as a dependency to your project.

Comment: Won't compile with scala 2.11

Comment: @tiran probably meant weakTypeOf. I've fixed the code.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako even though `weekTypeOf` would a nice addition to the "specialty menu"